E11000 duplicate key error collection: ShopCart.tokens index: sellerId_1 dup key: { sellerId: ObjectId('66af901a089b822f1dc3ff7d') }
First time mail successfully send but if i send mail again then showing this error
E11000 duplicate key error collection: ShopCart.tokens index: sellerId_1 dup key: { sellerId: ObjectId('66af901a089b822f1dc3ff7d') }
this is my seller route  post request for send email code------
router.post("/send-email", async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const seller = await Seller.findOne({email: {$regex: '^'+email+'$', $options: 'i'}});
  if(!seller) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Seller not found to reset the email" });
  }
  const payload = {
  email: seller.email
}
  const expiryTime = 500;
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: expiryTime});

  const newToken = new SellerToken({
    sellerId: seller._id,
    token: token
  });
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: "vishal.hariyani41@gmail.com",
      pass: "vdzpqeillbxoxkja"
    }
  });

  const mailDetails = {
    from: 'vishal.hariyani41@gmail.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Reset Password!',
    html:
        `<html>
      <head>
            <title>Password Reset Request</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Password Reset Request</h1>
        <p>Dear ${Seller.name},</p>
        <p>We have received a request to reset your password for your account with ShopCart. To complete the password reset process, please click on the button below: </p>
        <a href=${process.env.LIVE_URL}/reset/${token}>
        <button style="background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; padding: 14px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 4px;">Reset Paswword</button>
        </a> 
        <p>Please note that this link is only valid for a 2mins. If you did not request a password reset, please disregard this message.</p>
        <p>Thank you,</p>
        <p>ShopCart Team</p>
      </body>
      </html>`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailDetails, async(error, data) =>{
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Something went wrong when email send" });
      } else {
        await newToken.save();
        return res.status(200).send({ message: "Email Sent Successfully"})
      }
    });
});

and seller token code
// Forgot Password Code 
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
    sellerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "seller",
        unique: true,
    },
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 3600 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Token", tokenSchema);

